# How to get transfer time for Pool requests in guzzle6?

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

I want to get transfer time for each request. 
How I can use `on_stats` option for async requests?
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#on-stats

My code:

```
<?php
use GuzzleHttp\{Pool, Client};
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\{
Request, Response
};

$httpClient = new Client();
foreach ($items as $request) {
    $requests[] = new Request(...);
}

$responses = Pool::batch($httpClient, $requests, ['fulfilled' => function($response, $index) {

});
```

Comment: Check this example and see if it helps .. http://guzzle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request-options.html#on-stats

Comment: @Nevermore I don't know how use it in PSR7 Requests

Comment: @iilexial Check if this one helps .. http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/psr7.html

Comment: @Nevermore I know about this page. There are no examples with `on_stats` option on this page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

```
$responses = Pool::batch($httpClient, $requests, ['fulfilled' => function($response, $index) {

}, 'options' => ['on_stats' => function(TransferStats $stats) {
//..
}]]);
```